# Why doesn't ARIMA work on my time series data?

Tags: python, time-series, auto, arima

I use auto_arima from python library pmdarima.arima to predict a time series. However, the model seems not work on my data because the prediction results of both training and test data are pretty bad. I would like to know it is because somewhere I did wrong or the data is unpredictable by ARIMA. Here is what I did.

b is my 5-month time series with 700 observations evenly distributed. I first checked if the data is stationary by ADCF.

```py
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller

print("Results of Dicky-Fuller Test:")
dftest = adfuller(b, autolag='AIC')

dfoutput = pd.Series(dftest[0:4], index=['ADF Statistic','p-value','#Lags Used','Number of Observations Used'])
for key,value in dftest[4].items():
    dfoutput['Critical Value (%s)'%key] = value

print(dfoutput)
```

The results are here

```py
-----------------------------------------
Results of Dicky-Fuller Test:
ADF Statistic                   -2.045778
p-value                          0.266868
#Lags Used                       9.000000
Number of Observations Used    690.000000
Critical Value (1%)             -3.439863
Critical Value (5%)             -2.865738
Critical Value (10%)            -2.569005
dtype: float64
-----------------------------------------
```

It looks a stationary data to me. Then I use auto_arima to find the best parameter combinations and do the fit as well as prediction

```py
from pmdarima.arima import auto_arima

model = auto_arima(b, start_p=1, start_q=1,
                           max_p=6, max_q=6, m=1,
                           seasonal=False,
                           d=0, trace=True,
                           error_action='warn',  
                           suppress_warnings=True, 
                           stepwise=True)
print(model.aic())

model.fit(train)

prediction1 = model.predict(n_periods=len(train))
prediction2 = model.predict(n_periods=len(test))

#plot the predictions for validation set
plt.plot(time_train,train, label='train')
plt.plot(time_test,test, label='test')
plt.plot(time_train, prediction1, label='prediction1')
plt.plot(time_test, prediction2, label='prediction2')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

And here is the result. [Data and Predictions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7AEB.png)

Comment: You may get more help over at https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Since no one answered this question, I want to address here that the data was not quite suitable for ARIMA. I got pretty good prediction result (R2=0.94) by Random Forest.

Comment: Predictions are built incorrectly. For train predictions you should use model.predict_in_sample() and for future periods model.predict(len(test)). If you look more attentively, currently you have prediction1 and prediction2 the same, just with different number of periods.

Besides, your series is definitely not stationary. Leave d=None for auto_arima to check if some diffs can help with making it stationary.